# Why is my program not reading from the file?

Tags: c++, file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ifstream fin ("data1.txt");
    int ID;
    string name;
    int test1, test2, test3;

    char answer;
    cin >> answer;
    while (answer = 'Y')
    {

    fin >> ID;
    getline(fin, name);
    cout << name << endl;
    fin >> test1, test2, test3;

    cout << ID << endl;


    cout << test1 << "\t" << test2 << "\t" << test3 << "\t";
    cin >> answer;

    }
}
```

http://postimg.org/image/fjknavue9/    (Image showing the error)

It showing this error.
For some reason it is just reading the first ID. And then garbage.

```
This is the TXT file
211692
Ahmed, Marco
66 88 99
240885
ATamimi, Trevone
30 60 90
281393
Choudhury, Jacob 
45 55 65
272760
De la Cruz, Edward
79 89 49
199593
Edwards, Faraj
90 56 96
256109
Edwards, Bill
93 94 95
246779
Gallimore, Christian
22 88 66
270081
Lopez, Luis
100 100 100
114757
Mora, Sam
63 78 88
270079
Moses, Samuel
48 95 99
193280
Perez, Albert 
97 57 0
252830
Rivas, Jonathan
44 56 76
252830
Robinson, Albert  
85 87 89
276895
Miranda, Michael
82 72 62
280515
Robinson, Iris 
64 78 91
```

Program wwill only read the first id, but nothing else, yet it will display whats given, if not garbage. With knowing the solution or understanding, what is going wrong, it can help me in another program that deals with the same logic.

Comment: `answer == "y"`, not `answer = "y"`.

Comment: and `fin >> test1 >> test2 >> test3`, not `fin >> test1, test2, test3`.

Comment: If your compiler didn't give you a warning that showed the problem, get a new compiler. If you turned off its warnings or ignored them -- don't do that.

Comment: Also, do not use both `operator>>` and `std::getline()` together. That's just a recipe for grief, and heartache.

Answer (score 0):

As @Akshat Mahajan mentioned two problems in your code, I fixed and tested them.

One more thing is needed. You should add a line `fin.ignore()` to ignore the the new line after taking an integer from file.

Here is the working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ifstream fin ("data1.txt");
    int ID;
    string name;
    int test1, test2, test3;

    char answer;
    cin >> answer;
    while (answer == 'Y')
    {

        fin >> ID;
        fin.ignore();
        getline(fin, name);
        cout << name << endl;
        fin >> test1>> test2>> test3;

        cout << ID << endl;


        cout << test1 << "\t" << test2 << "\t" << test3 << "\t";
        cin >> answer;

    }
}
```

However, you have done some bad practice in your code. Instead of using `answer == 'Y'` as the condition of while, try something like `fin>>ID`.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to use getline for everything, you can change your code a little bit as below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ifstream fin ("data1.txt");
    int ID;
    string name, line;
    int test1, test2, test3;

    char answer;
    cin >> answer;

    while (answer == 'Y')
    {

        getline (fin, line);
        ID = stoi(line);
        getline(fin, name);
        cout << name << endl;
        getline(fin, line);
        stringstream ss(line);
        ss >> test1 >> test2 >> test3;

        cout << ID << endl;
        cout << test1 << "\t" << test2 << "\t" << test3 << "\t";
        cin >> answer;
    }
}
```